# How to define the header of sql output that contains Space in c# ViewModel?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database

I have a stored Procedure `stp_GetContractBillingDetailReportEquinoxByResultGrouping` which gives the output say (for example)

`First Name`  `Last Name`   `Department ID`  are the Column Header the output. I defined this in ViewModel as

`public string FirstName{ get; set; }`

`public string LastName{ get; set; }`

`public string DeptID{ get; set; }`

Due to the space in SQL output column The value is null how can I do so that the value of sql header First Name is assigned to viewmodel object FirstName without changing anything on database?

I tried using DisplayName

```
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName{ get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string LastName{ get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Department ID")]
        public string DeptID{ get; set; }
```

but didn't work

Comment: Is this Entity Framework?

Comment: If you are using Entity framework then try  with [Column("Name")] attribute in your data entity lass other wise try with a (underscore) _ e.g. First_Name

Comment: Yes it is entity farmework but using [Colomn("Name")] didn't help the value is still displayed as NULL

Comment: In the code you have shared its [DisplayName("Department ID")], add [Column] attribute to your entity class